# Unable to use paramerized query in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

[image]I am working with Nodejs/expressjs and right now i am tyring to execute parametrized query,But i am getitng following error in my console.log,How can i solve this ?

```
SyntaxError: Missing initializer in destructuring declaration
```

Here is my code

```
[![static async addServiceDetail(shopId,serviceId,genderTypeId,price,serviceName)
    {
        const sql = `SELECT id from hc_servicesdetail WHERE shopId='${shopId}' AND  serviceId='${serviceId}' AND genderTypeId='genderTypeId'`;
        const \[rows, fields\] = await pool.execute(sql);
        if(rows<1)
            {
                const sql2 = `INSERT INTO servicesdetail (userId, serviceId, genderTypeId,price,serviceName) VALUES (?, ?,  ?, ?, ?)`,\[userId, serviceId, genderTypeId, price, serviceName\]`;
                console.log('query is '+ sql);
                const \[datass, _\] = await pool.execute(sql2);
                console.log('last inserted id is ' +datass.insertId);
            }
        else
            {
                console.log('already exist');
            }   
    }
}][1]][1]
```

Comment: Remove ` from the end of [userId, serviceId, genderTypeId, price, serviceName]

Comment: @Konrad can you please edit in my code so i can check at my side

Comment: @Konrad if i remove then what should be there ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to assign two values to the same variable:

```
const sql2 = `INSERT INTO servicesdetail (userId, serviceId, genderTypeId,price,serviceName) VALUES (?, ?,  ?, ?, ?)`,\[userId, serviceId, genderTypeId, price, serviceName\]`;
```

You need two variables to hold two values:

```
const sql2 = `INSERT INTO servicesdetail (userId, serviceId, genderTypeId,price,serviceName) VALUES (?, ?,  ?, ?, ?)`;
const values = [userId, serviceId, genderTypeId, price, serviceName];
```

Full code:

```
class x {
  static async addServiceDetail(
    shopId,
    serviceId,
    genderTypeId,
    price,
    serviceName
  ) {
    const sql = `SELECT id from hc_servicesdetail WHERE shopId='${shopId}' AND  serviceId='${serviceId}' AND genderTypeId='genderTypeId'`;
    const [rows, fields] = await pool.execute(sql);
    if (rows < 1) {
      const sql2 = `INSERT INTO servicesdetail (userId, serviceId, genderTypeId,price,serviceName) VALUES (?, ?,  ?, ?, ?)`;
      const values = [userId, serviceId, genderTypeId, price, serviceName];
      console.log("query is " + sql);
      const [datass, _] = await pool.execute(sql2, values);
      console.log("last inserted id is " + datass.insertId);
    } else {
      console.log("already exist");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: query is not working